# I've lost my original OpenID login, how do I get it back?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

I've been using this account for the last 6 years:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/12424/bob-probst and my login for that account was an OpenId account which has now gone defunct.

I followed the account recovery processes but I seem to have wound up with a brand new account (this one).  Is there anyway to merge my old account with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your two accounts in our internal merge queue and merged them. You should be all set.

---

Generally speaking (just to provide some more widely-applicable advice for future readers)... contacting us via the contact form linked at the bottom of any site is the best way to handle this, since that allows you to easily provide any private info (like emails on the account, IPs, etc.) that may be needed for ownership verification.